# Grafana Influx string display the first three words

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I am currently building a Grafana dashboard for Canon printers. I would like to display the toner name. But only the toner, not the color. So the first three words. How can I do this?

Grafana currently displays the following:
`Canon C-EXV 49 Black Tone`
But I would like to have the following:
`Canon C-EXV 49`

I have already done the following with Regex, and it works:
`(\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+)`
[see screenshot from regex101.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x2bH.png)

The InfluxDB query is:

```
from(bucket: "snmp_monitoring")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["host"] == "mon02.bilten.resilux.corp")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["agent_host"] == "$snmp_agent_host")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "SuppliesDescription_BlackToner")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: last, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "last")
```

[This is the current state in Grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmGNx.png)

How do I get Grafana to change the VALUE of the field?

Thank you for your help

[image: Table view of the panel to comment @markalex]

Comment: Can you show your panel when *Table view* is ticked on top (in the edit mode of the panel)?

Comment: Thank you @markalex. I have updated the post and added a screenshot.
We have several Canon printers that have different toners (color printers as well as black and white printers). But since all of them have at least a black toner, I have this value that I query.

Comment: You can try Overrides > Value mappings, and extract first three words there: Regex `(\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+).*` Display text `$1`. Not sure if it will work for what seems to be a Stat panel, though.

Comment: Ferenc, if this comment helped you, please consider writing an answer based on it. It would be easier for you to describe what exact steps you've taken.